# web traffic capacity of the SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

how we can find out the web traffic capacity of the SharePoint farm by using a Microsoft Visual Studio Team System project file?

Answer (score 0):

check out this link: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758659.aspx

After the test environment is functional, it is time to create and fine-tune the tests that will be used **to measure the performance capacity of the farm**. This section will at times make references specifically to **Visual Studio Team System (Team Test Load Agent)**, but many of the concepts are applicable irrespective of which load test tool you use.

You can also use the SharePoint Load Test Kit (LTK) in conjunction with VSTS for load testing of SharePoint